# How to download movies or software?

Tags: release-freya

How can I download movies or other software from the internet on elementary? When i try to download it downloads a small file (my download manager is flareget) and then i click on it and... nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to have anything to do with elementary OS

Comment: @DanielForé Fore He may be asking something like "I was using this X service and when I try to download at x OS (e.g. Windows), I was be able to download but now in elementary OS , I can't so which app should I use?)

Question needs to be clarified but it doesn't mean it is not related to elementary OS. Assuming he just come from Windows or Mac OSX to elementary OS, where is he going to ask those questions?

Comment: @l.tim can you clarify the question? Which service were you trying to use? Were you be able to download movies before but now you can't, etc. We need to know more about your problem so if it's about elementary OS or related to it, you can ask at here. Else it may flagged as "non related" and closed down.

Comment: The question has now been edited to point out the that original poster is using flareget, not the default file downloader in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

**Uninstall flareget.**

This may seem a little hard, but if you're using a third-party download manager and you're having issues downloading things, it's probably the download managers fault. Instead, try using the downloader that comes integrated into your browser of choice.

Comment: it doesnt work i already tried

Comment: It doesn't work? What error go you get if you try wget?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a set of solutions for this problem.

- try using a different download manager, my recommendation is the Open source [Uget](http://ugetdm.com).
- try using the web browser's download manager.
- try to download a little smaller files to check if its not the fault of ISP.

Answer (score -2):

How about you try out online services like google movies? There you can build up an online library with legal movies and stream them to all your devices. Be it smartphone, tablet or desktop.